# Google Spreadsheets: Show Document URL in cell. Possible?

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell

Simple Question: I would like to get the URL of the active Document (google spreadsheet) in a specific cell.

So if I enter **=GetUrl()** in **A1** of https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&usp=drive_web#gid=16

should give me the result
**https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&usp=drive_web#gid=16**
in the cell A1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function like this might be useful:

```js
function GetUrl() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return ss.getUrl();
}
```

[image]

Check: [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) - [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getUrl())