# How to get the sheets key of a google sheet into a cell in the sheet automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to get the sheets key of a google sheet into a cell in the sheet automatically?

Now I am copying the key from the url, but I want the key to show up automatically in a cell in the sheet. Is it possible with a formula or apps script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Spreadsheets: Show Document URL in cell. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119558/google-spreadsheets-show-document-url-in-cell-possible)

Comment: If I could remove the url part. I only need the sheets key

Comment: you can then use the formula - =MID(A1,FIND("=",A1)+1,FIND("&",A1)-FIND("=",A1)-1) to get the sheets key out of the url. Where A1 is the cell you have used the previous answer

Comment: I have created a booking system with a sheet for each event. I have also created a number of sheets to collect data from the individual booking-sheets with the importrange function. A sheet for our bookkeeper. A sheet for our google site intranet and so on. I need the key for the importrange function in the collecting sheets.

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work. Probably because i'm in Denmark and the comma has to be replaced by semicolon.. I'm strugling.. :-)

Comment: does this version work - =MIDT(A1;FIND("=";A1)+1;FIND("&";A1)-FIND("=";A1)-1)

Comment: I evalueringen af FIND blev "=" ikke fundet i (not found in) "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iOxDvQXIImQcsKjOogZNrmCW3U4m2hyKC7gjKLhGfLQ/edit".

Comment: Hey. I think the geturl is enough. It turns out that the importrange function can work with the complete url :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For sheetID, put in a cell

```
=mySheetId()
```

after validating this script in your script editor

```
function mySheetId(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
}
```

### For spreadsheetID, put in a cell

```
=mySpreadsheetId()
```

after validating this script in your script editor

```
function mySpreadsheetId() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
}
```

Comment: Hey Mike. Can you make it so it gets the key and not the ID?

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand what is the key of a sheet? can you show within the url?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g-pTIRwcPP3ZLifGsjMylCNw4ScysV-X4IInhihSdTk/edit#gid=0  -----  1g-pTIRwcPP3ZLifGsjMylCNw4ScysV-X4IInhihSdTk

Comment: ok, this is not the key but the spreadsheet id

Comment: ok. I just used the term 'sheets key'.. But how do I call it with a script?

Comment: ok, I have edited my answer, take the second script (spreadsheetID)

Comment: Thanks Mike. It works :-) Turns out that the importrange function also works with the full url. But with the myspreadsheetid script I save a lot of time because I dont have to change a lot of formulas in the sheets